# XCode 9 unable to build - linker fails with "File not found" on object files - project builds fine in XCode 8.3.3

Tags: xcode

Here's a frustrating one.  My project builds perfectly in 8.x versions of XCode, and yet in 9.x versions, it fails consistently in the linker phase, as the linker is unable to find the .o file for a seemingly random class.

For example, in one build it will be unable to find the intermediate object file for my UIWindow subclass:

[image: XCode linker error screenshot]

In other builds, other files may be identified as the culprit, with the same "file not found" linker error.

So, clearly there is a disconnect in the linker phase.  I can understand that.  But I cannot make it work to save my life.

Here's what DIDN'T work:

• Deleting derived data

• Cleaning and option-cleaning

• In the .swift file inspector, removing the file from the target and re-adding to target

• Renaming the target

• Deleting the supposedly erroneous files from the project, and moving to trash, then re-adding the files to the project and target.

• Switching advanced workspace settings for Build Settings from "XCode default" to "Legacy"

• Updating XCode from 9.0 to 9.0.1

• Deintegrating Cocoapods and reinstalling them

Jeez.

So, none of the usual suspects are at play here.

Additional details :

• When I look in the folder specified in the linker error message, the .o files are NOT THERE. (Are they not being created? Is there a setting for that?)

• Using Mac OS High Sierra on a MacBook Pro Retina 15

So there's my conundrum.

**Does anyone know why XCode 9 would either not be creating .o files, or would be unable to find those files, for a project that build perfectly in previous versions of XCode?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was admittedly pretty painful.  I created a new project and then re-imported all the files and dependencies into the new project.  Then setup all the build settings, etc.  At that point the project was back to building and working fine.

If this happened again, I would try deleting the .xcworkspace file and re-generating it with `pod install` first before starting a new project.

May this not happen to you.